# How to get already saved file in file upload control in replace of 'No file choosen' in Edit mode in asp.net C#?

Tags: asp.net

I saved my file in location and get path & file name in database with file upload control.After this when I edit the form then did not get the saved file in file upload cantrol.It showing the blank file upload cantrol.How its possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a path to a file upload element. If this means that your web application overwrites the file info when editing, then do a check if a file was actually uploaded when editing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You're talking about an edit form, meaning the file was uploaded already before you show the edit page. Then you can't assign the filename to the upload element.

Comment: File was already uploaded and saved on location. I only want to that file return back into file upload cantrol in edit mode.If we cannot do this process then any other process we can apply ? Or Can we apply this preocess, first remove that file from file control and upload new content on that file control ?

Comment: You cannot assign anything to an upload control.